# Window.open pop up freezes the whole desktop

Tags: javascript, .net, windows, internet-explorer-11

I am having this strange problem. I have an application and I am doing an window.open from the start page. I have written the code as below:

```
i=1;
while i>0
{
 if (!mywindow.closed)
{
mywindow.focus()
}
else {
1--;
}

}
```

This is to make sure that the pop up window always stays in focus unless it is closed.
But the problem happening is, when the pop is there the whole desktop is getting freezed. we cant do anything else unless we close it. our intention was to freeze the application but not entire desktop. How can we solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `1--` actually `i--` in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript is not multi-threaded; if you run a `while` loop, it will tie up the whole execution of JavaScript. In other words, `mywindow.closed` will never get a chance to change.

If you want to respond to something changing, don't use a polling loop. Use an event instead:

```
// Not sure if this would work, but illustrates using events.
mywindow.addEventListener('blur', function () { 
  mywindow.focus(); 
});
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. My problem is not with the application but is freezing the entire desktop, like I cant check my mail or open a doc or anything else unless that pop up is closed. is that expected?

Comment: That little loop will take up as much CPU as it can; whether your desktop freezes depends on how much spare CPU is left over, so it makes sense that it'd be happening.

Comment: That explains it. Thank you. :)